# Reserve App Name and Delete

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Here is scenario

1. We were implementing an app for one of our client. He asked us to reserve name for the app. Now since he didn't own itunesconnect account at that time. We created and reserved app through our itunesconnect account.
2. Once we finished app and his account was created, we thought we can simply transfer app name to new account holder.

Well we then realize its not that simple

***Possible available solutions***

1. Itunesconnect allows only apps that are published ( Client didn't wanted to release app under our iTunes account but release under his name ). So this scenario didn't worked
2. Delete app ( This didn't worked as we can only delete app which are live)
3. Auto delete app ( I think it get's deleted after some days.. i think 170 ( I might be wrong ) ). Client was not ready to wait for that time.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know?

**PS - Please do not rate -ve to my question** :). I already have solution to my question just wanted to know proper way to implement this as well as reason behind apple restricting deletion of app's which are not live

Comment: Why have you put your solution in the question? if you have a solution to your own question just leave an answer like you have done. Removing the solution which worked section as this isn't needed here.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution which worked**

We deleted bundle ID from developer account and simply updated app name with new random key as _1. e.g.

Existing Name - **XXX**

New Name - **XXX_1**

This worked now we were able to register name **XXX** on new iTunes account :) but name **XXX_1** still stays on our account.

Comment: Similar thing don't put your question in your answer. Removed the question